# Using Window.rowsBetween in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, window

I am trying to create a window for a certain number of rows from the a CSV file like the following:

[image: csv file]

For instance, I need to count how many class in a window with size of 5 rows to get these results:

[image: results] 
and to count how many class 1 and the other classes were in this window.
I tried to use Window function. I am trying with this code:

```
val winSpec =  Window.rangeBetween(0, 5)
val dff = df.groupBy("time").agg(count("time").over(winSpec))
```

I would like to know how to control the `rangeBetween` to start from the first row or any row and stop at certain row e.g. 10.

Comment: Images are never good. try to add a small subset of data to the question and the expected output for that data.

Comment: Thanks for your note. Just wanted to give an idea of what I am looking for. So I am looking for how to create a window and controlling in its size then I can apply different operations based on the window's size. For instance, calss 1 repeated 3 times in the first window...etc